# Angular2 Dynamically add component to parent

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used this link to create a directive that dynamically loads a componet - [link](http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2/)
My problem is that I need to add the component to the parent rather than the current ViewContainer. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Background - I am loading the component dynamically within a bootstrap modal. The component is getting cut as my overflow is set to hidden. So I need to have the component outside of the modal such that I can position it over the modal.

Here is the code for the directive

```js
import {
    ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef,
    Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter,
    HostListener, Input, Output, Renderer,
    ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { AutoCompleteComponent } from './auto-complete.component';

import { AutoComplete } from './auto-complete.model';
import { Contact } from './contact.model';

@Directive({
    selector: '[AutoComplete]'
})
export class AutoCompleteDirective {

    autoCompleteComponentRef: ComponentRef<AutoCompleteComponent>;

    @Output() onContactSelected = new EventEmitter<Contact>();

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {
    }

    @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
        this.search();
    }

    private search()
    {
        if (this.autoCompleteComponentRef == undefined) {
            let autoCompleteComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AutoCompleteComponent);
            this.autoCompleteComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(autoCompleteComponentFactory);


            this.autoCompleteComponentRef.instance.onBusinessContactSelected.subscribe((x) => {
                this.onContactSelected.emit(x);
            })
        }
        this.autoCompleteComponentRef.instance.search(this.forename, this.surname);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker with your modal?

Comment: Essentially you want to add it to a target